# Strange multi-threaded behavior in electron's renderer process

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, electron

Consider the following code.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let loops = 0;

function loop() {
    fs.readdir(__dirname, () => {
        loops++;
        console.log('loop1 #' + loops);
        loop();
    });
}
loop();

setInterval(() => {
    loops++;
    console.log('loop2 #' + loops);
}, 100);
```

There are two async loops incrementing the same value. One uses `setInterval`, the other uses one of node's async methods. If you run this with basic node.js and place a breakpoint within either callback, the execution stops, as expected.

But now place this code inside `renderer.js` of a [boilerplate electron.js app](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) and place a breakpoint within the second loop.

A strange thing happens.

[image: strange]

It seems, even while Loop 2 is paused, Loop 1 continues working, printing the "loop1 #xxx" output to the console and updating the shared memory.

The effect only happens if I pause inside a browser-native async method (`setInterval`, `setTimeout`) and observe a node-native effects. All other combinations (browser -> node, node -> node, browser -> browser) pause all execution, as expected.

How is this possible? It's almost like electron has two javascript run loops that are kind of welded together and the debugger only affects the "browser's" run loop.

If this is the case, are there threading implications of this behavior? Do I have to add locks to the code that is shared between node and browser-based callbacks?

Comment: `require('timers').setInterval` will actually pause loop1, when setting a breakpoint.

Comment: @RoyalBingBong Good point. It definitely looks like there are two run loops happening here. I'd be curios to hear about the threading implications.